# Using Timer Interupt + ADC with DMA doesnt work at STM32F072CBTx

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

today I'm trying to use Interrupt for TIM1 or TIM15 (doesnt matter) and a DMA Access for the ADC using HAL:

```
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc, &buffer, 1);
HAL_Delay(500);
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim1);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_Delay(500);
```

But the program crashes after Start DMA or Start IT. Its not debugable. If I use just one of each other everything works.

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Please try with TIM14 and tell me if your program still crashes.

Comment: Hi tried. Still crashes. But for now it looks like that the Start DMA produce the problem. Now I cant use it anymore. I dont know why.

Comment: Could be missing Capacitors on the hardware cause that problem?

Comment: I asked you to try TIM14 because TIM14 doesn't use DMA, at least that's what the whitepaper says. If you ask me, there is probably some misconfigured macro, which causes the system to crash. Better don't use those macros and do it all yourself. Read the datasheet of your µC. Very often only a specific combination of functions is able to work together, so read all the little hints in your datasheet. Maybe start with the DMA function of your µC and check which other functions take advantage of DMA. Maybe you need to do some synchronizing, before enabling other things. **Check DMA channels too!**

Comment: What capacitors are missing?